# Simple type specifier is template parameter

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to ISO 14882:2011 § 14.6.2.1:

> A type is dependent if it is — a template parameter,

And according to § ISO 14882:2011 14.6:

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
>   the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
>   by the keyword typename.

But

```
template <typename T> class U
{
    typename T t; // ill-formed, i have an compilier error
};
```

Are "dependent name" and "name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter" the same concept?
I try to resolve my missunderstanding, since it looks as collision between  assertions in standard(ISO 14882:2011 § 14.6.2.1) and example from standard T t;.

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: `typename T t;` is ill-formed because [the grammar requires a nested-name-specifier](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#3).

Comment: Grammar doesn't require nested name specifier everywhere for typename, its only particular case for obligate using of typename. There are many cases where typename is required, but  nested name specifier is not applied. For example p<T>.x

Comment: I try to resolve my missunderstanding, since it looks as collision between 2 assertions in standard.

Comment: more precisely, assertion in standard 14882:2011 § 14.6.2.1 and example from standard: T t;

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is ill-formed, because of ISO section 17.7.3 (http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#3): `T` is not a `nested name-specifier`.

Hence, there's no way `T` can be anything else but the `typename T` used as the template parameter. I.e. the compiler can't be mistaken, so you don't need to qualify it with the `typename-specifier`.

An example of a dependent type where the `typename-specifier` is required would be `T::value_type`, because the actual type/value of `value_type` *depends* on what `T` is. In that case you have to help the compiler out:

```
template <typename T> class U {
  using t = T;                      // OK
  using u = T::value_type;          // ill-formed: needs typename-specifier
  using v = typename t::value_type; // OK: qualified with typename keyword
};
```

Let's say you have the following:

```
class foo {
  constexpr static int value_type = 7;
}

class bar {
  using value_type = int;
}
```

This is the reason the 2nd typedef line above is ill-formed: if `T` is `foo` then `value_type` is not actually a type, but a constant with a very confusing name. If `T` is `bar` then all is well. But the compiler can't know this, so you have to help him out and assure him `value_type` is in fact a type. That also means you will be greeted with a compile error if you ever try to compile `U<foo>`.

Note: I used C++11 syntax for the typedefs, because I find it much more readable. The explanation above still holds if you use `typedef` instead of `using`.

Comment: > "`T` is not a dependent name in your example."

 Why ? According to ISO 14882:2011 § 14.6.2.1: A type is dependent if it is — a template parameter, 
And dependent type is kind of dependent name according standard.

Comment: Please, justify your answer according iso 14882

Comment: I got an errors. see wandbox.org/permlink/FIMBqI579385nbhy How do you explain that standard asserts: 14882:2011 § 14.6.2.1: A type is dependent if it is — a template parameter, ???

Comment: I got the same result in class scope: https://wandbox.org/permlink/Zdm245quHUTZTYjK

Comment: I try to resolve miisunderstanding, since some assertions in standard, denoted above, look as contradictory.

Comment: I use this code only for example of declaration of data member. My question related to relations between standard assertions!!! I know, that code is ill-formed. I want to understand why ?

Comment: I don't try to declare type alias in class scope by typedef.

Comment: @Pupkin Ah, I must have read over the "mistake" in your example code at least 10 times :). Sorry for that! The `typename` is not allowed here because `T` is not a `nested name-specifier` (Section 17.7.3). As also noted by @cpplearner.

Comment: I very well understand Section 17.7.3, but those assertions it is not rule, apllied everywhere, but only where "When a qualified-id is intended to refer" It is only particular case. This rule don't imply the rule for all cases.

Comment: @Pupkin I don't quite understand what you're trying to say here.

Comment: I try to resolve my missunderstanding, since it looks as collision between standard assertions, donoted in top post and axamples, denoted in top post.  please see top post. I dint refer to draft 17.7.7.3.

Comment: And 17.7.7.3 don't resolve a collision because 17.7.7.3 explicity denote scope of apllying for itself: "When a qualified-id is intended to refer"